# Find the first Poulet number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A Poulet number (OEIS $A001567$)  is  called  a composite number $n$ such that $2^{n-1}−1$ is divisible by $n$. The first such a numbers are:
$$
341, 561, 645, 1105, \ldots
$$
**Question:**  How  to prove  that $341=11 \cdot 31$ is the fist Poulet number and there are not any another such a number which is less than $341$?

Of cource,  it is easy to show  by direct calculation in any computer system but I hope it can be proved by elementary numbers tools.

Comment: Hint: Proving this is the same as proving that $341$ is the smallest [base-2 Fermat pseudoprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime).

Comment: I know  that that is  the same numbers but how to  prove it?

Answer (score 2):

Showing that $2^{340} - 1$ is divisible by $341$ is routine.  Showing that $2^{n-1} - 1$ is not divisible by $n$ for any odd composite $< 341$ would appear to require looking at a lot of cases one by one.  It is all "elementary" but will take some time by hand.

Comment: Please give a sample for any  case $<341.$

Comment: One sample is to ask if $15$ divides $2^{14}-1=16383$  It does not.  In general $3$ divides $2^{2k}-1$ and does not divide $2^{2k+1}-1$, so if $3$ is a factor of $n$, then $n$ must be even.  This will eliminate a fair number of potential $n$ less than $341$